# Should I "mark as fixed" outdated URL errors in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

I'm looking at a bunch of URL crawl errors in google webmaster tools.  But they were all detected over a month ago, which was the last time I had updated my sitemap.xml in GWT (I switched servers and forgot to set up regular updates again).

I restructured the website and have a new sitemap that takes care of all of the outdated URL errors.  The sitemap no longer points to pages that aren't there.  Or at least it appears that way.  I don't want to go through and check each one.

If I "mark as fixed" but it's still a broken link will GWT find the broken link the next time it checks and alert me again?  Or will the broken link forever be passed over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are fixed and you mark them as fixed, they won't show up again.
If they are not fixed and you mark them as fixed, they will show up again.